# Ошибка msbuild в compact framework

Tags: c#, msbuild

Есть проект C# библиотеки VS2012. Настроили nant для построения для разных framwork-ов, но при Compact возникает ошибка:

```
  [msbuild]   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.targets(23,9): error : This project requires .NET Compact Framework v3.5, which is not installed on this machine. [C:\project_name\trunk\project_path\ProjectName.csproj]
```

Предварительно в проект добавил:

```
<Project>
  ...
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" Condition=" '$(COMPACT)' != 'true' " /> 
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.Targets" Condition=" '$(COMPACT)' == 'true' " />
</Project>
```

Ссылки на библиотеки тоже подправил:

```
<Project>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" Condition=" '$(COMPACT)' != 'true' " />
    <Reference Include="System" Condition=" '$(COMPACT)' == 'true' ">
      <HintPath>$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Причем, в решении уже есть проект, который также для compact строится, успешно, от которого зависит этот новый проект.
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Хм, вы вручную редактировали файл проекта? Неслабо.

А MSBuild строит?

Comment: Да, вручную, в том то и дело, что не строит. Проект создавал в `VS2012` указав 2.0 framework. Разрабатываем и локальные тесты проводим в vs. Потом подкорректировал вручную для возможности построения в compact (ссылки системных библиотек, targets и т.д.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было подкорректировать конфигурацию построения проекта для `Compact`:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'CompactFramework %28Debug%29|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\CompactFramework %28Debug%29\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;COMPACT;SAMPLE_CONSTANT;</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <!-- следующие строки надо добавить -->
    <COMPACT>true</COMPACT>
    <PlatformFamilyName>PocketPC</PlatformFamilyName>
    <PlatformID>4118C335-430C-497f-BE48-11C3316B135E</PlatformID>
    <OSVersion>5.1</OSVersion>
    <DeployDirSuffix>ProjectDirSuffix</DeployDirSuffix>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <NativePlatformName>Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK</NativePlatformName>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

И обернуть `AssemblyFileVersion` в Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
#if !COMPACT
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
#endif
```